# Issue to use nodes are in different machine in version 3.1

Tags: corda

Currently,I am trying to change the version from 1.0 to 3.1 . here, i have already deployed the nodes in different machine and gave IP address of network map node as network service. But now, no network map concept. i have gone through the documents  and got point as nodeinfo. how to use that to know the admin or server machine instead of network map IP and how to mention the IP of admin to other nodes which is in different machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corda nodes: how to connect two independent pc as two nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241773/corda-nodes-how-to-connect-two-independent-pc-as-two-nodes)

Comment: Thanks @joel. am try to download tool using  http://downloads.corda.net/network-bootstrapper-corda-X.Y.jar. but 404. how to find network-bootstrapper jar?

Comment: But it got struck while downloading and failed to download due to server problem

Comment: Sorry, that link has changed. Please use https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-network-bootstrapper/3.2-corda/corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda.jar instead.

Comment: where i have to place that jar file? from where i would start executing network-bootstrapper jar? i couldn't follow the document

Comment: i placed the network-bootstrapper jar at root of the nodes folder and executed. but i got it as no main manifest attribute, in corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda.jar

Comment: You have to download the excutable version.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you saw @joel's comments, the recommendation here is the executable version of the corda network bootstrapper jar.

Here's an example on how to use it :

Create a directory containing a node config file, ending in “_node.conf”, for each node you want to create. If you use one of the sample projects, they almost all have deployNodes gradle tasks that will generate these files for you.

```
java -jar network-bootstrapper-4.4.jar --dir <nodes-root-dir>
```

For example running the command on a directory containing these files:

```
.
├── notary_node.conf             // The notary's node.conf file
├── partya_node.conf             // Party A's node.conf file
└── partyb_node.conf             // Party B's node.conf file
```

Here's a link to the corda docs page on the bootstrapper: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html#bootstrapping-a-test-network

Lastly; you can find the latest version of the jar online here: https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-tools-network-bootstrapper/