# Flow is hanging at Collecting counterparties signature in Corda

Tags: corda

I am trying to run Example Cordapp in two AWS instances. With Notary and PartyA in 1st Instance and PartyB and PartyC in 2nd Instance.

I followed the steps here, 
[Corda nodes: how to connect two independent pc as two nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241773/corda-nodes-how-to-connect-two-independent-pc-as-two-nodes)

In the conf file of,

1. Notary and PartyA - I have edited the P2P address to reflect the PrivateIP of Instance 1
2. PartyB and PartyC - I have edited the P2P address to reflect the PrivateIP of Instance 2

With the above conf files, I ran the Network Bootstrapper jar in Instance 1 and copied the folders PartyB and PartyC to Instance 2 and started the Notary and Parties 1 by 1 respectively in the corresponding Instances.

All nodes started succesfully and when I try to execute a IOU flow from PartA(in Instance 1) to PartyC(in Instance2), it is pausing at **Collecting counterparties signature** step without proceeding further. Below is what I see in PartyA's Console,

```
Fri Nov 30 08:39:10 UTC 2018>>> flow start ExampleFlow$Initiator iouValue: 50, otherParty: "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR"
Verifying contract constraints.
Signing transaction with our private key.
Gathering the counterparty's signature.
Collecting signatures from counterparties. (hanging here and not proceeding further)
```

When I tried to look at the log information in NodeA, it displays as below.,

```
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:10,077Z [main] messaging.RPCServer.start - Starting RPC server with configuration RPCServerConfiguration(rpcThreadPoolSize=4, reapInterval=PT1S, deduplicationCacheExpiry=PT24H) {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:10,115Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] bridging.BridgeControlListener.processControlMessage - Received bridge control message Create(nodeIdentity=DLHBP432vnpLNpCNwGQJjx3hd6RDz4LiYxmZJo757W8Hbw, bridgeInfo=BridgeEntry(queueName=internal.peers.DL9tRWQ867M3tni7KRqkXEJKPrkyW5KVj6fyRyDBHGaGA6, targets=[[2001:0:9d38:953c:3c:ce3:cbd9:3c59]:10013], legalNames=[O=PartyC, L=Paris, C=FR])) {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:11,072Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.nextTarget - Retry connect to [2001:0:9d38:953c:3c:ce3:cbd9:3c59]:10013 {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:12,171Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2001:0:9d38:953c:3c:ce3:cbd9:3c59]:10013 {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:14,172Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.nextTarget - Retry connect to [2001:0:9d38:953c:3c:ce3:cbd9:3c59]:10013 {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-30T08:39:15,175Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to [2001:0:9d38:953c:3c:ce3:cbd9:3c59]:10013 {}
```

I could able to ping between instances with the private IP's without any issues. Can someone help me where am I missing things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in the logs of PartyB and PartyC?

Comment: Joel, the transaction was not reaching PartyB or PartyC. 

Then I tried disabling the firewall in both the instances and by adding "Custom TCP Rule - Port Anywhere" in the instance security group I was able to achieve things. Is there anyway without disabling firewall we could achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by a firewall on the node's machine that was preventing the node's messages from reaching the counterparty nodes.

You need to open:

1. Outbound ports for your node's P2P address
2. Inbound ports for the other nodes' P2P addresses

On a large network, this can mean opening many inbound ports, which can be an issue for some companies' security policies. This issue is addressed by the [Corda Firewall](https://medium.com/corda/peer-to-peer-enterprise-blockchain-networking-with-the-corda-firewall-4f6a427ebd97).