# Problem when connecting corda node in AWS

Tags: corda

Have referred to previous post about deploying nodes on two different machines [Corda nodes: how to connect two independent pc as two nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241773/corda-nodes-how-to-connect-two-independent-pc-as-two-nodes/45242522) . I tried to follow the steps and successfully changed the parameter in node.conf by using network bootstrapper tool. When I checked the node info, the shell correctly returned the correct path address of the node that was in AWS. However, when I started a flow, the process stopped at collecting signatures from counterparty(Node in AWS). And there was no response when I run flow watch on the node in AWS. Hope someone can help me figure out the problem behind. 
The first thing that I thought of

The version of Corda is 3.0

Below is the image of networkMapFeed run on the node in AWS. As you can see the node "TMobile" had the correct p2paddress of AWS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCiNV.jpg

Below is the port list for the AWS EC2. I used HTTP port range for the test. Dont know if this is the reason of failing. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD5sv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can see that several nodes have addresses of the type "localhost:10002" or "localhost:10005". The AWS node will not be able to reach these nodes using that address. You need to give each node a proper IP address by which they can be reached over the internet.

Comment: so i followed your instruction and changed all nodes with the public ip of aws. however, after launching the nodes, the shell would close automatically. then the log said [ERROR] 2019-01-20T20:11:43,484Z [main] core.server.run - AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation {} .   so my first follow question is that which port number should i use for each port  and second question is that if it is possible that only keep p2pAddress in node.conf and delete rpcSettins and rpcUsers (just like notary)

Comment: If you delete the RPC settings, you will not be able to interact with the nodes. This is likely not desirable. Can you raise a separate question for your second issue and paste the full stack trace there?